# Can we write Mongo DB query in GraphiQL?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, mongodb-query, pymongo, graphiql

I want to know whether I can make use of the Mongo DB query for filtering the data in GraphiQL.

Actually, I made an API with PyMongo, flask & GraphiQL.

Ex - in Mongo DB inside a collection I have the following 5 documents -:

Data in Mongo DB

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3d"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:00:00"
} 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3l"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:01:00"
} 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3e"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:02:00"
} 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3z"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:03:00"
} 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3v"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:04:00"
}
```

Now without using GraphiQL I was executing this below query in MongoDB for filtering my data on the "Serial_No", "Time_Records" between "2020-05-01 06:00:00" & "2020-05-01 06:04:00", with a Limit of size = '2' & skip = '1' for pagination.

```
def get_filter_data(Serial_No, from_date , to_date ,number_limit,number_skip):
    data = coll.find({"Serial_No": Serial_No, "Time_Record" : {'$gt': from_date , '$lt': to_date}}).limit(number_limit).skip(number_skip)
    for col in data:
        pprint.pprint(col)
    print("Count is : ", number_limit)
    return data
```

I am happy !!!

It works and gives the desired output -:

Correct output I got after executing the above Mongo query:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3e"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:02:00"
} 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5ff6ad894d0d2a1c6ce0fc3z"},
"Serial_No":"1111",
"Time_Record":"2020-05-01 06:03:00"
}
```

Now I want to get the same output in GraphiQL

Basically, I am not sure how to make use of this query especially how to mention this part {'$gt': from_date, '$lt': to_date} in GraphiQL

```
coll.find({"Serial_No": Serial_No, "Time_Record" : {'$gt': from_date , '$lt': to_date}}).limit(number_limit).skip(number_skip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to utilise GraphQL native support from mongodb [Official Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/graphql)
which also includes [Custom Resolver](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/graphql/custom-resolvers)